# Adding .gif image in assets folder in android

Tags: android, webview, gif

When i add a gif image in assets folder it gives me errors that Content is not allowed in prolog. Please help.

C:\games\work\DEGREE\Sem 4\Android Projects\CoolUI\app\src\main\res\assets\space.gif
Error:(1, 1) Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.

> C:\games\work\DEGREE\Sem 4\Android Projects\CoolUI\app\src\main\res\assets\space.gif:1:1: Error: Content is not allowed in prolog.

If i clean the project, then add image and run the app,  it runs properly but the image is not displayed saying: FileNotFound.

I have tried the solutions posted online like taking into consideration (assets and asset, etc).

Comment: y do u want but images in assets , cant u use them from drawables

Comment: I want to display gif image in web view. In all the solutions i have seen they have saved it in assets folder. If its possible by storing it in drawables folder also, then please tell guide.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try moving the files to the raw folder? You can then reference them by using the R class. Otherwise, you can try moving the file to "src/main/assets" and then map the custom path in your build.gradle file like:

```
android { 
  sourceSets { 
    main { 
     assets.srcDirs = ['src/main/assets/'] 
    } 
  } 
}
```

Comment: Well i am kind of a beginner, so i am unaware of where the raw folder is. I tried to paste the image in assets folder but i am getting the error file not found.

Comment: By just putting a file in assets folder you will not get a message file not found. Only if you try to use it somewhere. So tell when/where/how please.

Comment: You can just create the "raw" folder in the "res" directory and then paste the files there. Then you can reference them by using R.raw.my_gif.

Answer (score 0):

Well it turns out to be a android studio problem. If you close and reopen android studio, you can successfully refer to the image. I also tried inserting more images. Only after I re-open studio, I was able to use them. Thanks for the help!